# Passing a column as a function parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue with passing the ta.customer_no as a parameter to the function that generates a table, which I am joining to ta.

```
SELECT 
    ta.customer_no,
    ta.first_name,
    tb.company_name
FROM
    table01 ta
JOIN   
    dbo.FUNC01(ta.customer_no) tb ON ta.customer_no = tb.customer_no;
```

The error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   The multi-part identifier "ta.customer_no" could not be bound.

Why can't it be bound?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use "cross apply" instead of "join", like the following

```
SELECT 
       ta.customer_no,
       ta.first_name,
       tb.company_name
FROM   table01 ta
CROSS APPLY dbo.FUNC01( ta.customer_no ) tb 
WHERE ta.customer_no=tb.customer_no;
```

As for why "cannot be bound", it is related to SQL Engine's processing logic order. In short, the "Join" operator is processed before "Select" operator, thus "Join" operator cannot recognize "ta.customer_no"

Comment: Genius!!
Thank you so much!!